# I'm trying to make an endless runners and for now, I have 2 tile prefabs that I want to repeatedly spawn

Tags: unity-game-engine, instantiation

zSpawn is the z position at where the tiles are spawning
Each tile is 66 units long
There are 2 tiles and they are both prefabs

```
    using System.Collections;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using UnityEngine;

    public class HurdleManager : MonoBehaviour
    {
      public GameObject[] tilePrefabs;
      public float zSpawn = 0;
      public float tileLength = 66;
        void Start()
        {
          SpawnTile(0);
          SpawnTile(1);
          SpawnTile(1);
          SpawnTile(0);

        }

        // Update is called once per frame
        void Update()
        {

        }
        public void SpawnTile(int tileIndex)
        {

        Instantiate(tilePrefabs[tileIndex],transform.forward* zSpawn, transform.rotation);
        zSpawn+=tileLength;
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

have you tried using recursive functions/coroutines? You can use recursive coroutines and have an empty transform spawn point that moves every time you have spawned an object.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class HurdleManager : MonoBehaviour
{
     public GameObject[] tilePrefabs; 
     public Transform spawnPosition = 0;
     public float tileLength = 66;

     private void Start ()
     {
         StartCoroutine(SpawnTile(0))
     }

     private IEnumerator SpawnTile(int tileIndex)
     {
         Instantiate(tilePrefabs[tileIndex], spawnPosition, Quaternion.identity);
         spawnPosition.z += tileLength; // move the spawn position

         yield return new WaitForSeconds(5f); // how long do you want to wait before spawning the next tile

         StartCoroutine(SpawnTile(Random.Range(0, tilePrefabs.Length))); // spawn a random new tile prefab
     }
 }
```

Comment: For this line:  public Transform spawnPosition = 0; it is giving an error that unity cannot implicitly convert Unity.Tranform to an int

Comment: Sorry, just use `public Transform spawnPosition;`.